# Calculating Order Form doesn't give results

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to create an order form for a client that allows a few of his clients to order parts and the form calculates the total and emails it to him.  went through a tutorial on another website after looking all over for what I wanted.  However, after making a few changes to the code, and placing it on my server for testing it isn't working. I didn't do anything special with the code because I wanted to test it before I added the 66 items. I really don't know anything about PHP or JS and am probably really over my head.  Any help here would be extremely helpful.

here is the html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Order Form</title>
<script language="javascript">
<!--//
function dm(amount) 
{
  string = "" + amount;
  dec = string.length - string.indexOf('.');
  if (string.indexOf('.') == -1)
  return string + '.00';
  if (dec == 1)
  return string + '00';
  if (dec == 2)
  return string + '0';
  if (dec > 3)
  return string.substring(0,string.length-dec+3);
  return string;
}

function calculate()
{
  QtyA = 0;  QtyB = 0;  QtyC = 0;
  TotA = 0;  TotB = 0;  TotC = 0;
  PrcA = 1.25; PrcB = 2.35; PrcC = 3.45;

  if (document.ofrm.qtyA.value > "")
     { QtyA = document.ofrm.qtyA.value };
  document.ofrm.qtyA.value = eval(QtyA);  

  if (document.ofrm.qtyB.value > "")
     { QtyB = document.ofrm.qtyB.value };
  document.ofrm.qtyB.value = eval(QtyB);  

  if (document.ofrm.qtyC.value > "")
     { QtyC = document.ofrm.qtyC.value };
  document.ofrm.qtyC.value = eval(QtyC);

  TotA = QtyA * PrcA;
  document.ofrm.totalA.value = dm(eval(TotA));

  TotB = QtyB * PrcB;
  document.ofrm.totalB.value = dm(eval(TotB));

  TotC = QtyC * PrcC;
  document.ofrm.totalC.value = dm(eval(TotC));


  Totamt = 
     eval(TotA) +
     eval(TotB) +
     eval(TotC) ;

  document.ofrm.GrandTotal.value = dm(eval(Totamt));

} 


function validNum(theForm)
{
  var checkOK = "0123456789.,";
  var checkStr = theForm.qtyA.value;
  var allValid = true;
  var validGroups = true;
  var decPoints = 0;
  var allNum = "";
  for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)
  {
    ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
    for (j = 0;  j < checkOK.length;  j++)
      if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j))
        break;
    if (j == checkOK.length)
    {
      allValid = false;
      break;
    }
    if (ch == ".")
    {
      allNum += ".";
      decPoints++;
    }
    else if (ch == "," && decPoints != 0)
    {
      validGroups = false;
      break;
    }
    else if (ch != ",")
      allNum += ch;
  }
  if (!allValid)
  {
    alert("Please enter only digit characters in the \"Class A quantity\" field.");
    theForm.qtyA.focus();
    return (false);
  }

  if (decPoints > 1 || !validGroups)
  {
    alert("Please enter a valid number in the \"Class A quantity\" field.");
    theForm.qtyA.focus();
    return (false);
  }

  var checkOK = "0123456789.,";
  var checkStr = theForm.qtyB.value;
  var allValid = true;
  var validGroups = true;
  var decPoints = 0;
  var allNum = "";
  for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)
  {
    ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
    for (j = 0;  j < checkOK.length;  j++)
      if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j))
        break;
    if (j == checkOK.length)
    {
      allValid = false;
      break;
    }
    if (ch == ".")
    {
      allNum += ".";
      decPoints++;
    }
    else if (ch == "," && decPoints != 0)
    {
      validGroups = false;
      break;
    }
    else if (ch != ",")
      allNum += ch;
  }
  if (!allValid)
  {
    alert("Please enter only digit characters in the \"Class B quantity\" field.");
    theForm.qtyB.focus();
    return (false);
  }

  if (decPoints > 1 || !validGroups)
  {
    alert("Please enter a valid number in the \"Class B quantity\" field.");
    theForm.qtyA.focus();
    return (false);
  }

  var checkOK = "0123456789.,";
  var checkStr = theForm.qtyC.value;
  var allValid = true;
  var validGroups = true;
  var decPoints = 0;
  var allNum = "";
  for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)
  {
    ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
    for (j = 0;  j < checkOK.length;  j++)
      if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j))
        break;
    if (j == checkOK.length)
    {
      allValid = false;
      break;
    }
    if (ch == ".")
    {
      allNum += ".";
      decPoints++;
    }
    else if (ch == "," && decPoints != 0)
    {
      validGroups = false;
      break;
    }
    else if (ch != ",")
      allNum += ch;
  }
  if (!allValid)
  {
    alert("Please enter only digit characters in the \"Class C quantity\" field.");
    theForm.qtyC.focus();
    return (false);
  }

  if (decPoints > 1 || !validGroups)
  {
    alert("Please enter a valid number in the \"Class C quantity\" field.");
    theForm.qtyC.focus();
    return (false);
  }


  calculate();
  return (true);
} 


//-->
</script>





    </head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="ordertest.php" name="Order_Form">
    <p>Please tell us who you are (<font color="#FF0000">red</font> denotes 
    required information):</p>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td width="340" align="right"><font color="#FF0000">Name</font></td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="200"><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="340" align="right"><font color="#FF0000">Email</font> 
            (Your confirmation will be sent here): </td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="200"><input type="text" name="Email" size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="340" align="right">Other Contact Info:</td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="200"><input type="text" name="OtherInfo" size="30" tabindex="1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="340" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>And tell us what you would like:</p>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table2">
        <tr>
            <td width="250" height="31"><b>Item Description</b></td>
            <td align="center" width="100" height="31"><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td align="right" height="31" width="60"><b>Price </b></td>
            <td align="right" height="31" width="140"><b>Total</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250">Class &quot;A&quot; Widgets</td>
            <td align="center" width="100">
            <input type="text" name="qtyA" size="5" tabindex="5" onchange="return validNum(document.ofrm)"></td>
            <td align="right" width="60">1.25</td>
            <td align="right" width="140">
            <input type="text" name="totalA" size="12" tabindex="99" onchange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250">Class &quot;B&quot; Widgets</td>
            <td align="center" width="100">
            <input type="text" name="qtyB" size="5" tabindex="5" onchange="return validNum(document.ofrm)"></td>
            <td align="right" width="60">2.35</td>
            <td align="right" width="140">
            <input type="text" name="totalB" size="12" tabindex="99" onchange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250">Class &quot;C&quot; Widgets</td>
            <td align="center" width="100">
            <input type="text" name="qtyC" size="5" tabindex="5" onchange="return validNum(document.ofrm)"></td>
            <td align="right" width="60">3.45</td>
            <td align="right" width="140">
            <input type="text" name="totalC" size="12" tabindex="99" onchange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" width="100">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="60">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="140">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250">
            <p align="right"><b>TOTALS:</b></p></td>
            <td align="center" width="100">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="60">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="140">
            <input type="text" name="GrandTotal" size="15" tabindex="99" onchange="calculate()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" width="100">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="60">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="right" width="140">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" width="550" id="table3">
        <tr>
            <td width="563">
            <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subButton" tabindex="50">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="resetButton" tabindex="50"></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the PHP file:

```
<? PHP
//uncomment for debugging
//print_r($_POST);

//make sure there is data in the name and email fields
if( empty($_POST["Name"]) )
{
    $error["name"] = "Name is required.";
    $Name = "";
}
else
    $Name = $_POST["Name"];

if( empty($_POST["Email"]) )
{
    $error["email"] = "Email is required.";
    $Email = "";
}
else
    $Email = $_POST["Email"];

if( empty($_POST["OtherInfo"]) )
{
    $OtherInfo = "";
}
else
    $OtherInfo = $_POST["OtherInfo"];



//check to make sure the qty fields are whole numbers
//but only check if there was data entered
if( !empty($_POST["qtyA"]) )
{
    if( is_numeric($_POST["qtyA"]) && ( intval($_POST["qtyA"]) == floatval($_POST["qtyA"]) ) )
    {
        //we have a whole number
    }
    else
        $error["qtyA"] = "Please enter a whole number for Class A Widgets.";
}

if( !empty($_POST["qtyB"]) )
{
    if( is_numeric($_POST["qtyB"]) && ( intval($_POST["qtyB"]) == floatval($_POST["qtyB"]) ) )
    {
        //we have a whole number
    }
    else
        $error["qtyB"] = "Please enter a whole number for Class B Widgets.";
}

if( !empty($_POST["qtyC"]) )
{
    if( is_numeric($_POST["qtyC"]) && ( intval($_POST["qtyC"]) == floatval($_POST["qtyC"]) ) )
    {
        //we have a whole number
    }
    else
        $error["qtyC"] = "Please enter a whole number for Class C Widgets.";
}


//we should have at least 1 item ordered in the form
if( empty($_POST["qtyA"]) && empty($_POST["qtyB"]) && empty($_POST["qtyC"]) )
    $error["no_qty"] = "Please enter at least 1 item to order.";


if( is_array($error) )
{

    echo "An error occurred while processing your order.";
    echo "<br>\n";
    echo "Please check the following error messages carefully, then click back in your browser.";
    echo "<br>\n";

    while(list($key, $val) = each($error))
    {
        echo $val;
        echo "<br>\n";
    }

    //stop everything as we have errors and should not continue
    exit();

}
//we do not need the rest of the form fields as we can just calculate them from the whole numbers
if( !empty($_POST["qtyA"]) )
{
    $qtyA = $_POST["qtyA"];
    $totalA = $qtyA * 1.25;
}
else
{
    $qtyA = 0;
    $totalA = 0;
}

if( !empty($_POST["qtyB"]) )
{
    $qtyB = $_POST["qtyB"];
    $totalB = $qtyB * 2.35;
}
else
{
    $qtyB = 0;
    $totalB = 0;
}

if( !empty($_POST["qtyC"]) )
{
    $qtyC = $_POST["qtyC"];
    $totalC = $qtyC * 3.45;
}
else
{
    $qtyC = 0;
    $totalC = 0;
}

$GrandTotal = $totalA + $totalB + $totalC;

//we have our data, and now build up an email message to send
$mailto = "mymail@atmygmail.com";
$subject = " Online Order";

$body  = "The following confirms the details of your order:\n";
$body .= "\n\n";
$body .= "Name: " . $Name . "\n";
$body .= "Email: " . $Email . "\n";
$body .= "Other Contact Info: " . $OtherInfo . "\n";
$body .= "\n\n";
$body .= "Class A Widgets: (" . $qtyA . " * 1.25) = " . $totalA . "\n";
$body .= "Class B Widgets: (" . $qtyB . " * 2.35) = " . $totalB . "\n";
$body .= "Class C Widgets: (" . $qtyC . " * 3.45) = " . $totalC . "\n";
$body .= "\n";
$body .= "TOTALS: " . $GrandTotal . "\n";

mail($mailto, $subject, $body);
mail($Email, $subject, $body);

//we should state the order was sent
echo "The following information was sent.";
echo "<br>\n";
echo "<pre>\n";
echo $body;
echo "</pre>\n";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already said that you may be in over your head, so I'll try and give you some direction here...

Don't get me wrong, we are all here to help, but there are some issues with what you have supplied and asked:

You don't really have a question yet. The reason it does not work is because there is an awful lot wrong. The only answer anyone can give you is to basically re-write it all.

The idea of StackOverflow is to ask questions to specific problems, and questions like 'all of this doesn't work' is not really answerable.

I can give you some pointers to some the errors, and if you can change the code accordingly, I'm sure someone (including myself) will be able to help. But if you cannot understand what is required, then some other assistance may be better.

So, here goes with a few observations:

Repeating the same code to do the same calculation for every item that may need it.

Code re-use is huge in this kind of scenario. You have repeated the same calculation in the same function 3 items, but you mentioned there are ultimately 66 items. Would you really want write these checks, validations etc. over again another 63 times?

Create a function that calculates, formats, or validates the data passed in as parameters. Do not repeat that code. This makes the code shorter, easier to read, simpler to debug and change.

Typo? document.ofrm. Did you mean document.form?

Regardless, this is not how you should access the DOM. Better is: document.getElementById(elementId) from the function.

You are re-declaring your variables in the same function; after declaring once, you just set their current value.

You are passing the wrong, invalid, or non-existent items to functions from the HTML.

Passing 'document.ofrm' to the validNum function from the inputs; just send 'this' (validNum(this)). Then you can get the value of the individual input that fired the onchange event.

I got as far as here when I realised that this is quite a re-design and re-code. Hope this helps...

Comment: I appreciate your candor. I was trying to take a tutorial online to help teach me how to create a form that would create an order that could be eMailed to the owner. I'll start over.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, we are all learning every day. And we are still here when you need more specific help...